# Converting floating-point values

Tags: c, floating-point, modulo

I'm trying to make the program to print out the floating-point value. I've tried putting `%f`, and it gave me the same number but with 0 at the end. In my function definition I tried to make `temp` double but it keeps saying "expression must have integral type."

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int modifyIntegral();

int main() {
    int value;

    value = modifyIntegral();

    printf("The Updated value : %d\n", value);   
}

int modifyIntegral() {
    double value;
    double temp;

    scanf_s("%d", &value);

    temp = (value < 0) ? -value : value;

    if (temp % 10 > temp / 100 % 10) {
        temp += -temp % 10 + temp / 100 % 10;
    }
    else {
        temp += 100 * (temp % 10 - temp / 100 % 10);
    }

    return (value < 0) ? -temp : temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the modulus (%) operator on a double.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your program.

First, `%` is an integer operator so you can't use it on floating-point types. Use [`fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead. But you can't get the digits of the floating-point values by getting the modulo 10 like that without removing the fractional parts

Second, you declared `value` as `double` but then read it as an int

```
scanf_s("%d", &value);
```

That would cause undefined behavior

I don't understand what you need to convert? Operations like what you did can be done and should be done in integer.